# How to create XML in Google custom search Autocomplete?

Tags: search, google-custom-search

I try to use the structure at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/queries but it can't upload successfully.

```
<Autocompletions>
  <Autocompletion term="cake" type="1" language=""/>
  <Autocompletion term="strawberry.*" type="2" match="2" language=""/>
  <Autocompletion term="vanilla" type="2" language=""/>
  <Autocompletion term="apple" type="3" language="">
    <Promotion id="1" queries="dessert" title="Apple pie for dessert!" url="http://www.example.com/applepieforsale"
        start_date="" end_date="" image_url=""  description="Apple pie is the best dessert ever!"/>
    <Promotion id="2" queries="apple" title="Buy Apple pie" url="http://www.example.com/applepieforsale"
        start_date="" end_date="" image_url="" description="We stock the best apple pie in the world, right here."/>
  </Autocompletion>
</Autocompletions>
```

My website is using wordpress; I get the title of posts and want to use it as string query for google custom search.

Please help me figure out how to create XML for autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

It's not liking the description attributes. It you remove those, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Leave all terms in XML like that:

```
<Autocompletion term="%term-title%" type="%type%" language=""/>
```

Be careful with the length of the terms, I found that if it is 3 or less words, Google will accept it fine. There is also no big restriction on ammount of entries you're adding (I added 9000 entries in one go). And I added them in Russian, so there are no problems with encoding either.

The final format should be like that:

```
<Autocompletions>
  <Autocompletion term="%term-title%" type="%type%" language=""/>

  ...

  <Autocompletion term="%term-title%" type="%type%" language=""/>
</Autocompletions>
```

Not terribly well documented by Google, so you have to waste time reading this. Hope it helps :)